# compute the probability

Tags: probability

I have 10000 students who responded to a test with 40 multiple choice items. Each item has 4 options (A, B, C, and D). Only one option is the correct answer.
What is  the probability of 5 (out of 10000) students got exactly the same response pattern? That is, pick the same option on each item for all 40 items (e.g., ABAACDDBBBC.....).

Of course, students have different abilities and items have different difficulty levels.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to frame a more precise hypothesis in order to obtain any useful answer.  The reason becomes clear when you consider the possibility that some students may get perfect scores on the test: that implies they all picked the same options on every item. The chance of that happening depends on how well prepared the best students are and the answer could lie anywhere from zero through 100%.  For this reason, most methods used to detect cheating focus on the *identical incorrect responses* and account for how many there are.

Comment: whuber is right. More precisely, this can only be computed when you specify a model that can be used to compute the probability for every student/item pair that the student gets it right. These may even depend on other students (for example in case they prepare together) or other items (covering the same knowledge area). The only straightforward model to compute this is assuming that every student responds to every question totally at random, independently. Under this model your question can be answered by standard arguments, but this is completely unrealistic.